# Set a non-scalar variable to null and return whatever it's referencing in a single statement?

Tags: flutter, dart

In a project I'm working on I have the following kind of operation in more than a few places:

```
MyClass obj = editObj;
editObj = null;
doSomething(obj);
```

The point of this is to set the *variable* `editObj` to reference `null`, while "transferring" whatever it's referencing to another variable so I can keep using it.

To put it into context, here's a very simplified program:

```
class MyClass{
  String text = '';
  MyClass(this.text);

  @override
  String toString() => 'MyClass{text: $text}';
}


MyClass editObj;


void doSomething(MyClass obj) {
  print('1 obj: $obj   editObj: $editObj');
  
  Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1), (){
    obj.text = 'two';    
    print('2 obj: $obj   editObj: $editObj');
  });  
}

void main() {  
  editObj = MyClass('one');

  MyClass tmp = editObj;
  editObj = null;
  doSomething(tmp);  
}
```

This prints

```
1 obj: MyClass{text: one}   editObj: null
2 obj: MyClass{text: two}   editObj: null
```

If `main()` instead looked like this

```
void main() {  
  editObj = MyClass('one');

  doSomething(editObj);
  editObj = null;
}
```

the results would be

```
1 obj: MyClass{text: one}   editObj: MyClass{text: one}
2 obj: MyClass{text: two}   editObj: null
```

Of course, I could simply set `editObj` to `null` at the start of `doSomething()`, but I'd rather handle it from the calling code.

Is there a less verbose way of achieving this? I'm thinking something like

```
doSomething(editObj = null) // Doesn't work
```

i.e. setting `editObj` (the variable!) to `null` while at the same time returning whatever it's referencing.

Comment: I am a little confused about your pattern here since I have never seen the need before. Why not do `doSomething(editObj); editObj = null;`?

Comment: @julemand101 I've added an example which clarifies why `doSomething(editObj); editObj=null;` is not the same thing as _first_ setting `editObj` to `null` and _then_ calling `doSomething()`. The key point here is that `editObj` is a "global" variable, i.e. it might be used by methods called from `doSomething`, for example to update the UI (in my case this is a Flutter app).

Comment: Ok, if it is a global field I think the best you can do is make a method which fetches the value and set it to null. Alternative you could pack the object inside a e.g. `Container<MyClass>` class (you need to make this) where this container has a method to fetch and set the value to null.